# TreePos in EA for elements

Tags: enterprise-architect

During creation of new elements in EA i tried to set the element position using Element.TreePos but after setting this still the element in EA is getting inserted based on the Alphabetical order. But once the project is reloaded it is getting arranged properly as per the TreePos.

```
EA.Element mobjElement= mobjParentelement.AddNew("","Requirement");
  mobjElement.Name= "Sample";
mobjElement.TreePos=1;
 mobjElement.Update();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reload before a change in TreePos becomes apparent.
You can use `EA.Repository.RefreshModelView(long PackageID)`. According to the documentation the `PackageID` parameter should limit the reload to only the package with the given ID, but I have not found a difference between reloading a single package or reloading the whole model (using 0 as parameter).

Since v13 there is also `EA.Repository.ReloadPackage(long PackageID)` which might do what you need, but I haven't tested that myself. From the documentation it is not clear what the exact difference is between the two operations.

Comment: Thanks EA.Repository.ReloadPackage(long PackageID) worked

Comment: I found the API to select in project browser

Comment: LOL _if a valid Package ID, only that Package is reloaded._ So, if not valid, it's not reloaded. Or will a flash strike from heaven and kill you instantly? Another mystery from Sparx.